# Alter Table Drop Column INPLACE NoLock - until which point is the column being dropped accessible?

Tags: mysql-5.7, alter-table, online-operations

I am trying to run MySQL Alter `INPLACE` command to drop few columns from a very large 90GB table. While the Alter is running I am able to run the Select statement on the same table to ensure that the table is not locked.

MySQL Version 5.7 with InnoDB

Questions:

1. While the alter command is running with in place algorithm and nolock, up to what point the data can be accessed in the columns being dropped? e.g. at the point when the columns are almost being dropped? I need to make this change in prod so need to make sure of this.
2. Can the application still update the table while the alter statement to drop the columns is running? Currently the columns are stored and after dropping them we will be adding them back as Virtual.
3. Will there be any downtime at all, I read somewhere  that the table will be locked shortly at the end, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. Basically I was asking if ONLINE DDL and concurrent operations in MySQL is allowed without downtime. As per MySQL official documentation since MySQL 5.6 and above concurrent operation is allowed for many different operations when you use ALGORITHM=ONLINE LOCK=NONE if you are using innodb NOT MyISAM.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html

[image]
[image]

I ran a test in my dev environment by running ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN and UPDATE statements concurrently. The UPDATE completed before the drop. I was able to query the updated column, it was showing the new updated values.